# Maven modules via setting paths, not copying folders

Tags: maven

Maven's multi-modules plugin doc [states](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects) clearly:

> Modules are regular Maven projects which must be located under a subdirectory so the parent project can retrieve them easily.

The thing is I don't want to locate them under a subdirectory. **I just want to point to some file path which can be used in order to compile dependencies.** (Highlighted, since this is the question actually).

The reason I want it is simple: I just don't want to mess two completely different paradigms - maven modules and git submodules - in one folder. Moreover, I don't want to have any kind of git dependencies in the project.

Solution number 0, i.e. to create simlinks and to put them to `.gitignore` does not count ;)

Comment: I am afraid that _must be located under a subdirectory_ means there is no way to change that. If that would have been possible, you'll have to configure the main pom to declare where are the children and in the children where is the parent. Nothing like that exists in maven.

Comment: @ZNK-M, but why child projects should even know about parent anything at all? (sorry if this question sounds stupid, may be I don't get it). Besides, from the point of view of the reactor project, what makes the difference: to get module via inspecting subfolder or via inspecting path setted?

Comment: why the child need to know the parent? To get the default plugin configuration, the common properties, the artifact versions, ... Why in maven they decided that it must be in the direct sub folder... and not configurable in contrary of everything else... this I don't know. But the organization allows the user to easily copy / access resources of another module (even if it is probably not a good practice) by using ${basedir}/../my-module/...

Comment: @ZNK-M it looks like I don't get the very idea of multiple modules - I've though that module is literally autonomous, so it can be used without reactor project at all. Thus, the idea it can check any kind of common properties seems suspicious to me. The only reason I need reactor project is not to recompile each project separately.

Comment: I entirely agree with you, they are **meant** to be autonomous. In practice, this is the case at the beginning of a project and after two weeks it becomes a spaghetti because it was easiest to copy a file from another module instead of configuring a plugin in maven... BTW, configuring all the versions of the dependencies in the main pom as the advantage to be consistent across all modules. If your need is just to execute multiple pom, maybe the modules aren't the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to create the directory structure within a single git repository and don't use submodules in Git. This will result in a structure like this:

```
root (pom.xml)
  +-- module1 (pom.xml)
         +-- src/main/java
         +-- src/test/java
  +-- module2 (pom.xml)
         +-- src/main/java
         +-- src/test/java
  +-- module3 (pom.xml)
         +-- src/main/java
         +-- src/test/java
```

The above structure will be put under Git version control with the root folder which comprises of the sub modules as well. Not submodules etc. in Git.
If you have dependencies in this scenario you have to use module dependencies which are the best practice in Maven.

Comment: but what is the point of keeping completely independent parts of project in a single repository. Whole idea is that even developer teams can be different, though this modules nevertheless are developed inside the company.

Comment: If these modules are independent than you should not use a multi-module build. Simply use independent maven projects with their own git repositories.

Comment: in that case if both modules are developed in a single company, I should compile module A if it depends from HEAD revision of module B, compile this module as well. On development stage it is not that rare.

Comment: That's exactly the reason having SNAPSHOT versions which are intended exactly for such purposes. (Best handled via a repository manager in a company).

Comment: sorry, can get you. Having SNAPSHOT version does not free me from need to recompile both modules, ain't it so?

Comment: Correct. It doesn't free you up from recompiling. But you might consider using an aggregation setup http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Aggregation.